# How to override Mage_Tax renderer in Magento

Tags: overriding, magento-1.9, tax

I want to override the `getShippingIncludeTax()` method in the class `Mage_Tax_Block_Checkout_Shipping` , this block is defined as a renderer in the config;

```xml
<sales>
    <quote>
        <totals>
            <shipping>
                <renderer>tax/checkout_shipping</renderer>
            </shipping>
        </totals>
    </quote>
</sales>
```

I can override a block if needed, but this class doesn't have any Block definition. How do I override this?

**NOTE:** *This is not a typical Block override.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a module that overrides Mage_Tax_Block_Checkout_Shipping...

```
 <global>
    <blocks>
        <tax>
            <rewrite>
                <checkout_shipping>Test_TestModule_Block_Tax_Checkout_Shipping</checkout_shipping>
            </rewrite>
        </tax>
    </blocks>
</global>
```